# In terminal I would use the vi command to create a file inside of a directory: `vi bot.py` (after doing mkdir supreme_bot) how could I do this on cmd?

Tags: python, windows, vim, cmd, vi

In terminal on mac I was able to the command In terminal `vi bot.py` to create a file inside of a directory. I would do `mkdir supreme_bot` and then do `vi bot.py` which would open a separate window to code and I could save it and move back and fourth between terminal and my work in progress code. On windows I did `mkdir supreme_bot` (which created the folder), but when I did `vi bot.py` it did not open that section. What is the command for that for cmd on windows?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In terminal I would use the vi command to create a file in a file: \`vi bot.py\` how could I do this on cmd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59279779/in-terminal-i-would-use-the-vi-command-to-create-a-file-in-a-file-vi-bot-py-h)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This probably happens because vi is a text editor that is installed on your Mac and is not installed on your Windows system. There should be an error message indicating that the `vi` command could not be found.
Try typing `notepad bot.py` instead of `vi bot.py` which will open the Windows default notepad.

However, if you like the style of the vi editor you can also install [vim on Windows](https://www.vim.org/download.php) and set it up for command line usage, see [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1026685/setting-up-vim-under-win-10). Afterwards, you can open and create files as you did before.

Comment: I just tried notepad and this is what what I said on my other question but have not got a response yet: I typed `dir /r` and the file bot.py appeared but the folder on my desktop is empty. Also notepad seems like it is a place where I will only be able to write things. I wanted to be able to write code and then be able to run it later on. On mac I just did `vi bot.py` and I was able to code on a file that would save as a .py file in the folder. I was wondering if there was and equivalent to that on cmd. I also tried to download vim but didn't know what to make it function the way I want on CMD